# Is there a good visual aid or picture to help understand openness and closedness?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling to grasp the idea of open, closed, clopen and not open and not closed sets in a more formal approach like how it's described in a math analysis class. Is there a good picture somewhere that can help describe it? Or perhaps you know how to describe it in a good way that differs from other textbooks?

Comment: Have you seen the pictures where open sets are the ones where you can draw balls around points that stay in the set?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon I think so, and the balls can get smaller and smaller right? But couldn't you draw a ball around points in a closed set too that don't necessarily break the "boundary"?

Comment: Sometimes. That is why being open and being closed are not incompatible.

Comment: Heurestically: open means there's a ball around each point that remains in the set, so no point in the set is near a boundary. Every point has a little "wiggle room". Closed means that you can't leave the set by taking a long journey (travelling towards a limit point). A lot of the time open sets fail to be closed, because you take a sequence of points with less and less "wiggle room", and if you head towards a limit point that is in the set, then it has no "wiggle room". However, there are no guarantees in general that you can find a sequence of points headed towards a limit point with less..

Comment: and less "wiggle room". This clearly fails if you take all of $\mathbb{R}$, because every point has an infinite amount of room to move around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closedness is checking the complement for openness.

If A has no boundary points , A is open.

If A has all the boundary points , A is closed.

Comment: would boundary points happen to be the same as limit points by chance? I think my professor described them as limit points. Possibly.

Comment: not the same...{0,1} has boundary points 0 and 1.So closed.but no limit points ..

Comment: Ohhh I think I'm getting something. So a set will have limit points only if there is a sequence of numbers whose limit converges to the limit point? And that limit point is like the "pretend" boundary(even though it's not)?

Comment: yes.limit points can be interior or boundary point of the set.limits points may not be element of the set.

Answer (score 0):

A set $A$ is said to be open if and only if $\operatorname{int} A=A$ and a set $A$ is said to closed if and only if the closure $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ equals $A$.

Comment: And how are you defining interior and closure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a metric space $X$, then a subset $S\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if, whenever $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq S$ is a convergent sequence with limit $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$, then $x\in S$. So a closed set is a set which you cannot escape using convergent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The following work in any metric space $X$.

Approach 1.

A set $B$ is *open* iff for all $b \in B$ there an $\epsilon$ of room. That is, a set $B$ is open iff for all $b \in B$ we can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $b$ is a subset of $B$. Thus an open set is "roomy" or "spacious." A set $B$ is *closed* iff for all $b \in B^c$ there an $\epsilon$ of room. That is, a set $B$ is closed iff for all $b \in B^c$ we can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $b$ is a subset of $B^c$. Thus a set is closed iff it has a "roomy" or "spacious" complement.

Approach 2.

A point $x \in X$ is a boundary point of $B$ (but not necessarily an element) if every (non-empty) ball centered at $x$ overlaps somewhat with $B$, and also overlaps somewhat with $B^c$. A set is open iff every boundary point of the set fails to be an element of the set. A set is closed iff every boundary point of the set succeeds in being an element of the set.